# How to open Android app list with appium?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I need to automate the verification of the notification badge on the app icon on Android. The problem is Android places icons in the app list menu, which is opened by swiping the main screen up. Is there a way to get into that app list menu in Android using appium?

[image]

Comment: are you using uiautomator

Comment: @PDHide yes, I'm using UIAutomator.

Answer (score 0):

**Imports required:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy.ByAccessibilityId;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;

import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption.point;
```

**Code:**

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Users\\prave\\Downloads\\ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AVD, "Pixel_XL_API_30");
    
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "io.appium.android.apis");
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos");
    
    
    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(capabilities);

    driver.longPressKey((new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME) ));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(ByAccessibilityId.AccessibilityId("Apps list")));
    MobileElement elem = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Apps list");
    new TouchAction(driver).press(point(elem.getLocation())).moveTo(point(elem.getLocation().x, -500)).perform();
```

**Explanation**

Appium has keypress event but the key press event for "KEYCODE_ALL_APPS" is not working . so you have to goto home by clicking `driver.longPressKey((new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME)));`

Once there, identify the element "arrow key" to swipe up, now use that element to swipe up using action class